# What is the function of では in this context?

Tags: translation, particles

I was trying to translate this text and I didn't understand the use of the では particle. I thought it might be something like “with this body without feet, hands and wings I am the serpent of the world”, but I'm not confident.

> 五つの陸を食らい尽くし三つの海を飲み干しても空だけはどうすることもできない
>
> 翼も手も足もないこの身では
>
> 我は世界蛇

Comment: Isn't there some noun between 飲み干しても and だけは?

Comment: Yes, it is 空. I'm very sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

この身では modifies どうすることもできない. Your citation has the following two sentences, with the first one being a 倒置文 (anastrophe/hyperbaton).

- 五つの陸を食らい尽くし三つの海を飲み干しても、翼も手も足もないこの身では空だけはどうすることもできない。
  Even though I devoured the five continents and drained the three seas, there's nothing I can do about the sky with this body that has neither wings, nor hands, nor feet.
- 我は世界蛇(だ)。

Comment: Could it be something like that too? “even if I devour the 5 continents and drain the 3 seas, there is nothing I can do about the sky with this body that has no wings, no legs, no hands”

Comment: @mentasugar Yes, I incorporated that in my answer.